# Why is to_char used when doing a divide by 0 in Oracle based SQLi?

Tags: oracle, security, sql-injection

For conditional-error-based SQLi, instead of writing 1/0 directly like MYSQL, we need to write to_char(1/0) for Oracle, what is the reason behind this? Example,

Oracle:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (YOUR-CONDITION-HERE) THEN TO_CHAR(1/0) ELSE NULL END FROM dual
```

Microsoft:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (YOUR-CONDITION-HERE) THEN 1/0 ELSE NULL END
```

Reference: https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/cheat-sheet#conditional-errors

Comment: what happens if you do omit  the to_char function?

Comment: If I remove to_char I get an error irrespective of the condition.

Comment: No, that is not true. You get an error if the condition is true and you get not error if the condition is wrong

Comment: How does the answer accepted by you explain why a conversion to character is used in case of Oracle but not in case of Microsoft?

Comment: You're right, Microsoft's documentation for CASE also suggests the same thing as Oracle. I ran the commands on oracle database and it is not giving an error there. However, it does give an error on actual target machines when trying to inject it as sqli payload.

Any other reason why it needs the to_char?

Answer (score 0):

The first possible result of the `case when` expression determines the output type. All potential results must conform to the same output type. You would use to_char or cast to tell Oracle that the remaining options are also `varchar2`